# Classpath reading in Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, classpath

```
$ $CLASSPATH
$ $ source .profile
$ $CLASSPATH
> bash: :/usr/java/connectors/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar: No such file or directory
$ /usr/java/connectors/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar 
> no main manifest attribute, in /usr/java/connectors/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is, when I run it from $CLASSPATH (to see if it has been set) why it's not being detected.  Shouldn't it be the same if I type it in?  I'm getting two different results.

the connector is 0777 with owner root:root.

Comment: What does '$' and '>' at the beginning of the line mean?

Comment: $ means "this is something I'm typing as my user (not root)"
> means "this is something the console has returned"

Comment: So you typed `$CLASSPATH`, then you typed `.profile`, then you typed `CLASSPATH` (without `$`) and got error message?  So that is `CLASSPATH` command?

Comment: sorry the third line has $CLASSPATH, it's an environment variable I set in profile... that should also be "$ source profile" I'll edit now.

Comment: Are you exporting the CLASSPATH environment variable?  Either in your script or on the command line you need: export CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't solve the problem as I'd like I have found a solution.

In this instance I'm trying to add a JDBC connector so I can use it in my Java programming.  In Eclipse I've been able to go configure build path -> add variable -> configure, then define CLASSPATH as the .jar file.

If anyone still has an answer for the posted question I would be very interested to know.